# Basic HTML with Pattern.web

Tags: python

I am trying to scrap the following information from IMDb:

- Budget
- Weekend gross (in US)
- Screens (associated with weekend gross, US only)

Desired Output: 
 
**$220,000,000 (estimated), $207,438,708 (USA), (4,349 Screens)**

I wrote the following code to get the HTML seen below:

```
from pattern import web
import requests

url_business = url_movie = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/business"
business_html = requests.get(url_business)
dom = web.Element(business_html.text)

for business in dom.by_id('tn15content'):
    print business.source
```

The output (truncated) looks like this:

```
<div id="tn15content">


<h5>Budget</h5>
$220,000,000 (estimated)<br/>
<br/>

<h5>Opening Weekend</h5>
$207,438,708 (USA) (<a href="/date/05-06/">6 May</a> <a href="/year/2012/">2012</a>) (4,349 Screens)<br/>&#163;15,778,074 (UK) (<a href="/date/04-29/">29 April</a> <a href="/year/2012/">2012</a>) (521 Screens)<br/>$178,400,000 (Non-USA) (<a href="/date/04-29/">29 April</a> <a href="/year/2012/">2012</a>)<br/>BRL 20,387,104 (Brazil) (<a href="/date/04-29/">29 April</a> <a href="/year/2012/">2012</a>) (996 Screens)<br/>$51,640 (Cambodia) (<a href="/date/05-17/">17 May</a> <a href="/year/2012/">2012</a>)<br/>INR 110,000,000 (India) (<a href="/date/04-27/">27 April</a> <a href="/year/2012/">2012</a>)<br/>&#8364;4,752,836 (Italy) (<a href="/date/04-29/">29 April</a> <a href="/year/2012/">2012</a>) (678 Screens)<br/>PHP 277,383,923 (Philippines) (<a href="/date/04-29/">29 April</a> <a href="/year/2012/">2012</a>) (479 Screens)<br/>&#8364;468,100 (Portugal) (<a href="/date/04-29/">29 April</a> <a href="/year/2012/">2012</a>) (80 Screens)<br/>
<br/>

<h5>Gross</h5>
```

Because the text is not within any tag, I cannot do `element.by_tag().content`. So how do I get the information?

Comment: Can you not use beautiful soup?

Comment: This is part of the code, rest of which is all done in pattern.web. I could do it with bs4 but would like to keep everything uniform. Also, it's good to learn pattern.web.

Comment: Ok got it - you've got `business.string` attribute - can you not parse that? eg. `business.string.split('<h5>')[1]` - will give you desired string. Agreed very hacky - but that's essentially what screen scraping is.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hmm....I get an attribute error. "AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'string'".

Comment: If I append every value in business, I get the following: [Text(u'\n'),
 Element(tag=u'h5'), Text(u'\n$220,000,000 (estimated)'),...] showing the first three elements of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I have got so far - I think it should be easy to take it from here

```
from pattern import web
import requests
import sys

url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/business"

r = requests.get(url)
if not r.ok:
    sys.exit(-1)

d = web.Element(r.text)

x = d.getElementById('tn15content')
```

split the text of the Dom element `x` by .

```
strs = x.string.split('<h5>')
```

First two items

```
print strs[0]
print strs[1]
```

Here are rest of the elements, split them by `<br />`

```
b = strs[2].split(r'<br />')
```

Get rid of the `a href` string.

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'(<a.*a>)')
for i in b:
    print r.sub('', i)
```

Output:

    `Opening Weekend</h5>
    $207,438,708 (USA) () (4,349 Screens)
    &#163;15,778,074 (UK) () (521 Screens)
    $178,400,000 (Non-USA) ()
    BRL 20,387,104 (Brazil) () (996 Screens)
    $51,640 (Cambodia) ()
    INR 110,000,000 (India) ()
    &#8364;4,752,836 (Italy) () (678 Screens)
    PHP 277,383,923 (Philippines) () (479 Screens)
    &#8364;468,100 (Portugal) () (80 Screens)`

I think you can follow this to get desired output.